# Getting Data from 2 different MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project that involved getting information from two different servers. What i plan on doing is having the user enter his or her username password and then have a php script fill in the rest of the fields below first name last name etc. I did some searching and found that some of the data i have is on two different tables within the server. Below is the coding I have so far.

```
 <?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","**************","**********") or die ("Couldn't Connect"); //host,username,password
    mysql_select_db("*******") or die ("Could not find database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_users WHERE username='$username'");


    ?>
    <html>
    <form action="populate.php" method='post'>
     <table>
    <tr>
            <td>VAE&nbsp;Username:</td>

            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>VAE&nbsp;Password:</td>

            <td><input type='password' name='password' value=''></td>
          </tr>
     </table>
      <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search & Populate!'></p>
</form>
//below is the information i want filled in from the MYSQL tables
    <hr>
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_users WHERE username='$username'");
    <form action="dafreg.php" method='post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Fristname:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='firstname' value='<?php echo $firstname; ?>'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Lastname:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lastname' value='<?php echo $lastname; ?>'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Login:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='login' value='<?php echo $username; ?>'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='pass' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Country:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='country' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Pilot:</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pilot' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>ATC:</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='atc' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' value=''></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
     <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'></p>
     </form>





    </form>


    </html>
```

Comment: You don't make much sense. Are you on two different servers, databases or tables ?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could please strip off the unnecessary html and post only the part relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'JOIN' will be the best option for extracting the data multiple table...

```
SELECT tab1.*,tab2.*
FROM table1 tab1 JOIN table2 tab2
ON tab1.id=tab2.id
WHERE tab1.username=$username
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two tables are on the same database you could left join the two tables based on a common factor (probably username in this case)

```
SELECT *
FROM jos_users
LEFT JOIN table_name2
ON jos_users.username=table_name2.username
WHERE jos_users.username = $username
```